# Beanstalk not running makemigrations

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my Django server to Amazon through Beanstalk, and so far it's been ok except I've made a few changes to my models and when I deployed the instance on Aws is not updating accordingly.

I have followed the guide from amazon and created a file named db-migrate.config with the content

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: myAppName.settings
```

but obviously it doesn't seem to be working. I tried to access my django instance on Aws with

```
eb ssh myAppEnv
```

but when I enter I saw nothing and I couldn't find the code for my django server anywhere, thus i am unable to debug and manually run makemigrations also.

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Did you check the Elastic Beanstalk logs?

Comment: How can I check the beanstalk log? And I assume this is caused by makemigration was not called so I'm not sure if reading logs can help me with this.

Comment: @Sylph, you should be able to get the activity logs through `eb logs myAppEnv`. As for the location of your code on the EC2 instance, you can find the location of your code using `find / -name "<your project name"`

Answer (score 0):

Only way i was able to fix this was by specifying the exact applications i wanted to makemigrate and migrate.

```
02_migrateapps:
command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python3 manage.py makemigrations organisations shows media exhibitors && python3 manage.py migrate --noinput"
leader_only: true
```

It's a real pain but each time i make a new app i'll need to add it to the list of makemigrations.

Hope this helps.